# This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations

Tags: wordpress, validation, feed

Congratulations!
[Valid RSS] This is a valid RSS feed.

Recommendations
This feed is valid, but interoperability with the widest range of feed readers could be improved by implementing the following recommendations.

line 42, column 0: content:encoded should not contain style tag (4 occurrences) [help]

```
                <description><![CDATA[Artikel über Kameradschaft]]></description>
```

line 177, column 0: Invalid HTML: html needs to be the first start tag. [help]

How is this fixable?

Need help with that problem